# django .update() a foreign key

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

im having problems updating a fk.

**Views.py**

```
estandares = 
EstandarProducto.objects.select_related('recinto','producto','proveedor').prefetch_related
(Prefetch('carreras')).filter(recinto=id_recinto)


for proveedor in estandares:
    if proveedor.proveedor_id == None or proveedor == "":
                
    EstandarProducto.objects.filter(id=proveedor.id).update(proveedor_id=1)
    x=EstandarProducto.objects.get(id=proveedor.id)
    print("ID proveedor : ", x.proveedor.id )
```

**Models.py**

```
class EstandarProducto(models.Model):
    ''''''
    costo_unitario_uf = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=5, default=0)
    cantidad = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    total_uf = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=5, default=0)
    recinto = models.ForeignKey(Recinto, related_name='estandares_producto', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    producto = models.ForeignKey(
        Producto, related_name='estandares_producto', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    proveedor = models.ForeignKey(
        Proveedor, related_name='estandares_producto', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    carreras = models.ManyToManyField(Carrera, related_name="estandares_productos", blank=True)

class Proveedor(models.Model):
    '''Datos de contacto de un proveedor de cotizaciones o de estandar.'''
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    direccion = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
    correo = models.EmailField(blank=True, null=True)
    telefono = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.nombre} - {self.direccion}"
```

The problem is the print return 1 as expected, but when i look at the database there is no changes.

Comment: You said it reflected on the print,  the print just gets the value from the database, so either the database/table you are looking at or the record you are checking isn't the right one. I tried this on my end too and it worked.

Comment: i know it doesnt work because i get 3 prints and a error that only appears when i get a null value on a EstandarProducto at proveedor.id field.

Answer (score 0):

well, my mistake because i didnt update the estandarProducto instance, and that i was using on my JSON.